# Custom function not working properly as expected

Tags: php

`<?php if(isset($staff['FirstName'])){echo encodeToUtf8($staff['FirstName'];} ?>`

code above is the code source of my costume function, I create a function to make my code more shorter than the previous one.

this is my function:

```
function ifset($table_name, $field_name){
    if(isset($table_name[$field_name])){
      encodeToUtf8($table_name[$field_name]);
    }
    return $table_name;
    return $field_name;

  }
```

so that I can use the code must shorter like this `<?php echo ifset($staff, 'IDNumber'); ?>`

but it's not working, it give error : `Undefined variable` if `field` has no value and not what a expected.

have someone any idea about this case.

Answer (score 0):

You can't `return` two statements in a single function. You could return as an array.

```
function ifset($table_name, $field_name){
    if(isset($table_name[$field_name])){
      encodeToUtf8($table_name[$field_name]);
   }
   return array($table_name,$field_name);
}
```

You can then access it using a list.

```
list($table, $field) = ifset($staff, 'IDNumber');
```

Comment: Nope.  He just wishes to return one string.  Not an array.  His return statement is wrong, and yes, you can't have 2 returns.

Answer (score 0):

The return statement is wrong.  Here is the fix:

```
    function ifset($table_name, $field_name)
     {
        if(isset($table_name[$field_name]))
         {
          return encodeToUtf8($table_name[$field_name]);
         } 
        return ''; 
      }
```